# JS: change icon in div on Bootstrap collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok, I have tried several methods (JS and CSS) and I cannot get this to work. I need to change a plus font awesome icon to a minus (i.e either add a new div in place of the other or just change the class of the div) when a div is collapsed via Bootstrap.

I have looked at similar questions but can't solve this for the life of me.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">

                              <h4 class="panel-title">

                                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i><span style="margin-left: 12px; display: inline-block;"></span>Lab Focus: Cloud Management with vRealize Operations & <nobr>vRealize Automation</nobr></a>

                              </h4>

                            </div>


                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">

                                  <div class="panel-body">

                                      <span style="font-family:'proximanova-light', sans-serif;font-size:15px; line-height:19px; text-align:left; color: #565656;">

                                      <p>Deliver intelligent operations management across physical, virtual, and cloud infrastructures and accelerate the deployment and management of applications and compute services, improving business agility and operational efficiency.</p>
```

When I click the div and it opens (it is an accordion div) I need to change the `fa-plus-square-o` to `fa-minus-square-o`then back again when the div collapses. Because I have 8 of these, I have tried using JS and `this`:

```
     $(".collapsed").click(function() {
                    console.log("panel clicked");
                   var downPanel = "";
    $(this).html(downPanel);
                   $('.fa-plus-square-o', this).remove();
$('.fa-plus-minus-o', this).add();
                            });
```

And several other variations but nothing worked. I then tried CSS changing the class to collapsed1:

```
.collapsed1 .fa-minus-square-o,
.collapsed1.collapsed .fa-minus-square-o {
    display: inline-block;
}
.collapsed1.collapsed .fa-plus-square-o,
.collapsed1 .fa-plus-square-o {
    display: none;
}
```

However this results in either just the minus or both icons showing all the time. I am new to JS and need some help.

How can I change the icon depending on if the div is collapsed or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just toggle the classes:

```
$('.collapsed').on('click', function() {
 $(this).find('i')
   .toggleClass('fa-minus-square-o')
   .toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o')
});
```

Comment: Remove the dots before the class names inside `toggleClass()`